# Reverse Scrolling in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: gnome, touchpad, ubuntu-gnome, scrolling

I am using **Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20**.

After upgrading from GNOME 3.18 to 3.20, my mouse settings are reset.

I can't find options in Mouse & Touchpad Settings to set Reverse Scrolling (aka Natural Scrolling).

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll`?

Comment: `true`!! and also one more thing. I tried the same using gconf editor. Any changes made have **no effect**!!  I even disabled scrolling (for  testing), but it has no effect on my computer @ParanoidPanda

Comment: `gconf-editor` is really old, you should be using the pre-install `dconf-editor`. But it's very strange it's not working, perhaps this is a bug, you should file a report. They really are very good at fixing these things so reporting it would be the best.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I am sorry, its `dconf-editor` I used.  

Now I noticed that, any changes made in dconf, related to touchpad is having no effect [Edge scrolling, Tap to touch, ... all of it !!]

Comment: I think that it's probably just buggy... I am now running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20 and have just posted a similar question... I'm going to get in touch with upstream.